# Need to get the occurrence of same webelement locator and wherever present then click it

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I need the java webdriver to click a button on a page wherever it is present. No fixed number of occurrences of the element but its not more than 20.

i tried using:

```
 for(i=0; i<=20; i++){
            try{
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-small.btn-list")).isDisplayed();
                present = true;
            } catch(Exception g) {
                present = false;
            }
        if(present) {
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-small.btn-list")).click();
            WaitForPageToLoad(5);
        } else {
            System.out.println(i);
            break;
            }
        }
```

But this just works to click element 1 time, not for all occurrences. 
Please help.

Comment: Your if/else statement looks incorrect, the first time it doesn't find it on the page you're going to break out of your loop. Also this happens really quickly, do you need to wait for the page to load or anything if the element isn't present?

Answer (score 1):

Here, try something like this:

```
boolean present = false;
List<WebElement> els= d.findElements( By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-small.btn-list"));
d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
for ( WebElement we : els ) {
    try{
        if ( we.isDisplayed() ) {
            we.click();
            present = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invisible.");
        }
    } catch( StaleElementReferenceException|NoSuchElementException g) {
        System.out.println("WARNING: " + g.getMessage() );
    }
}
if ( present ) {
    System.out.println("Found bookoo!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Found nada!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach without using implicit waits but explicit which is more portable and maintainable when cross-browser and cross-platform testing. There is no need for your check to see if the element is visible/displayed as the WebDriverWait explicitly performs this for you.

[See the following](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) for more information on the different kinds of waits

```
   String CSS_SELECTOR = ".btn.btn-small.btn-list";

   webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector(CSS_SELECTOR)))

   List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(CSS_SELECTOR));

   for ( WebElement element : elements ) {

        element.click();

   }
```